# Google Analytics reporting doesn't display individual users for iOS app

Tags: ios, google-analytics, reporting

We've implemented user-level tracking using the documentation https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en, including creating specific reporting views User Behavior and Monitor User. Despite this, we cannot see any views in GA which display the individual user ids. How to do this? I'd like to be able to answer these kinds of questions:

- Which individual users are heaviest users of app, are what are
  specific flows, events that they are doing? What is their behavior
  like?
- Which individuals are lightest users of app?
- Which users have never used certain features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing comes very close violating the [Google Analytics TOS](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html). You need to ensure that you do not send any Personally identifiable information to Google Analytics.

The user id feature is more practically intended to [understand aggregate user behavior](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663?hl=en) and unify cross device sessions. If you rephrased your query to not get at individual users but groups you could easily answer some of your questions.

Which user groups are heaviest users of the application? create a segment which contains your definition for a user which makes heavy use of your application and query for the specific pages that segment visits.